# Functions that refer to the output of other functions - Python

Tags: python, function, random, nameerror, defined

I've been having trouble getting functions to work that rely on the output of another function. When I run the following code (this is a very simplified version)...

```
from random import randint

def event():
    if m == 1:
        r = randint(0, 4)
    else:
        r = randint(3, 7)

def random():
    if r == 1:
        print "Test A"
    elif r == 2:
        print "Test B"
    elif r == 3:
        print "Test C"
    elif r == 4:
        print "Test D"
    elif r == 5:
        print "Test E"
    elif r == 6:
        print "Test F"


m = 1
event()
random()

m = 2
event()
random()

m = 3
event()
random()
```

...I get `NameError: global name 'r' is not defined`

I need to keep these in separate functions because in my actual code they are very complicated. How can I get random() to recognise the random number generated by event()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to use `return` and `args`

```
def event():
    if m == 1:
        r = randint(0, 4)
    else:
        r = randint(3, 7)
    return r                        # return variable r here


r = event()                         # accept variable r here from event
random(r)                           # pass it to random function

def random(r)                       # receive r from the caller
    ....                            # Use r as a variable
```

Answer (score 0):

While returning a variable is a good way to achieve your goal, sometimes you do need to have [global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) variables. In that case, put `global r` in the definition of `event()` before you assign to it. e.g.:

```
def event():
    global r

    if m == 1:
        r = randint(0, 4)
    else:
        r = randint(3, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! "global r" worked in some parts of my code but threw me off later when variables kept being being reassigned.